# Azure Container Registry - keep last images

Tags: azure, azure-container-registry

I have 8 repositories in my Azure Container Registry. I want to create a Script that delete all images except the last 4 created. I found the following script:

```
$acrName = 'YourACRName'

$repo = az acr repository list --name $acrName

$repo | Convertfrom-json | Foreach-Object {
    $imageName = $_
    (az acr repository show-tags -n $acrName --repository $_ | 
       convertfrom-json |) Select-Object -SkipLast 4 | Foreach-Object {
           az acr repository delete -n $acrName --image "$imageName:$_"
       }
}
```

I want to test it in only one repository. How can I select only one?

Comment: Did the answer solve your problem? You can accept the answer. Or what's more, do you need?

Answer (score 0):

If you're okay with using any one, try:

`$repo = az acr repository list --name $acrName --top 1`

See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/acr/repository?view=azure-cli-latest#az-acr-repository-list

Comment: I received the following error:
Failed
At line:9 char:58
+ ...          az acr repository delete -n $acrName --image "$imageName:$_"
+                                                            ~~~~~~~~~~~
Variable reference is not valid. ':' was not followed by a valid variable name character. Consider using ${} to delimit the name.

Answer (score 0):

You can now use the Azure Cli acr purge command.

The line below will delete all images (--ago 0d) except the last 4 created (--keep 4)

```
az acr run --cmd "acr purge --filter 'my-image:.*' --ago 0d --untagged --keep 4" --registry mycontainerregistry /dev/null
```

- --filter - A repository and a regular expression to filter tags in the repository. Examples: `--filter "hello-world:.*"` matches all tags
  in the hello-world repositor, and --filter `"hello-world:^1.*"`
  matches tags beginning with 1. Pass multiple --filter parameters to
  purge multiple repositories.
- --ago - A Go-style duration string to indicate a duration beyond which images are deleted. The duration consists of a sequence of one
  or more decimal numbers, each with a unit suffix. Valid time units
  include "d" for days, "h" for hours, and "m" for minutes. For
  example, --ago 2d3h6m selects all filtered images last modified more
  than 2 days, 3 hours, and 6 minutes ago, and --ago 1.5h selects
  images last modified more than 1.5 hours ago.
- --untagged - Specifies that manifests that don't have associated tags (untagged manifests) are deleted.
- --keep - Specifies that the latest x number of to-be-deleted tags are retained.

See also:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-registry/container-registry-auto-purge

Comment: Hi Patrick, Can you please check this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71290848/acr-purge-how-can-i-set-regular-expression-to-skip-specific-image-which-starts