# ACR purge - How can i set regular expression to skip specific image which starts with v from purging

Tags: regex, azure, command-line-interface, azure-container-registry, acr

I am managing a Azure Container Registry. I have scheduled a ACR Purge task which is deleting all image tag if they are older than 7 days and exclude versioned images which are starting with *v*  so that we can skip certain image from cleanup.

For Example: if image has name like

```
123abc
v1.2
v1.3
xit5424
v1.4
34xyurc
v2.1
```

So it should delete images which are not starting with *v* and should delete the images which are not starting with *v*. For example it should delete below images-

```
123abc
xit5424
34xyurc
```

My script is something like this.

PURGE_CMD="acr purge --filter 'Repo1:.' --filter 'ubuntu:.' --ago 7d --untagged --keep 5"

az acr run
--cmd "$PURGE_CMD"
--registry Myregistry
/dev/null

Thanks Ashish

Comment: Hi Ashish, you can use a regular expression after the image name as a filter, like: hello-world:^1.* You can try for yourself (with —dry-run)  I’ll look at it on Wednesday.

Answer (score 2):

Please check if below gives an idea to workaround :

Here I am trying to make use of delete command .

> grep -v >>Invert the sense of matching, to select non-matching lines.
>
> Grep -o >> Show only the part of a matching line that matches PATTERN.
> [grep - Reference](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix_commands/grep.htm)

1)Try to get the tags which does not match the pattern "v"

```
$tagsArray = az acr repository show-tags --name myacr --repository myrepo --orderby time_desc \
    --output tsv | grep -v "v"
```

Check with **purge** command below if possible (not tested)

```
PURGE_CMD="acr purge --filter 'Repo1:.' --filter 'ubuntu:.' --ago 7d --filter '$tagsArray' --untagged --keep 5"
az acr run --cmd "$PURGE_CMD" --registry Myregistry /dev/null
```

(or)

check by using **delete** command

Ex:

```
$repositoryList = (az acr repository list --name $registryName --output json | ConvertFrom-Json)

foreach ($repo in $repositoryList)
{
$tagsArray = az acr repository show-tags --name myacr --repository myrepo --orderby time_desc \
    --output tsv | grep -v "v"

    foreach($tag in $tagsArray)
    {
            az acr repository delete --name $registryName --image $repo":"$tag --yes
        
    }
}
```

Or we can get all tags with a query which should not be deleted and can use if else statement tag .

```
foreach ($repo in $repositoryList)
    {

  $AllTags = (az acr repository show-tags --name $registryName --repository $repo --orderby time_asc --output json | ConvertFrom-Json ) | Select-Object -SkipLast $skipLastTags


$doNotDeleteTags=$( az acr repository show-tags  --name $registryName --query "[?contains(name, 'tagname')]" --output tsv)

 #or     $doNotDeleteTags  = az acr repository show-tags --name $registryName --repository $repo --orderby time_asc --output json | ConvertFrom-Json )  -- query "[?starts_with(name,'prefix')].name" 


foreach($tag in $AllTags)
    {

        if ($donotdeletetags -contains $tag)
        {
            Write-Output ("This tag is not deleted $tag")
        }
        else
        {
            az acr repository delete --name $registryName --image $repo":"$tag --yes
        }
 
    }
   }
```

**References:**

1. [fetch-the-latest-image-from-acr-that-doesnt-start-with-a-prefix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60416969/fetch-the-latest-image-from-acr-that-doesnt-start-with-a-prefix)
2. [azure-container-registry-delete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70360107/azure-container-registry-retention-policy/70378444#70378444)
3. [how-to-delete-image-from-azure-container-registry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41446962/how-to-delete-image-from-azure-container-registry/46920891#46920891)
4. [acr-delete-only-old-images-](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57908098/acr-delete-only-old-images-variable-reference-not-vald)